# Generate MiniDump on Address Sanitizer error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, address-sanitizer

I’ve compiled my Windows C++ application with Address Sanitizer and deployed it to a target machine. When I run it on the target machine, I get an ASAN error and I get a stack trace for the culprit thread.

I want to debug all the threads at this occurrence. Unfortunately I don’t have a debugger installed on the target machine and I don’t have remote debugging set up.

I have turned on WER for the application so I can copy the MiniDump file back to my dev machine to debug other types of crashes.

Can I do the same for ASAN errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you totally can do it. You need to set the environment variable, then Asan will generate the crash dump file for you.

`ASAN_SAVE_DUMPS=MyFileName.dmp`

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-offline-crash-dumps?view=msvc-170

Comment: Thank you! I had glossed over `ASAN_SAVE_DUMPS` thinking it was just saving the error message as a text file. Didn't realize it was an actual crash dump. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to produce a dump on my real application, though it does for a small toy example. I'll save that for another question though.